# show/hide content, show first one from start

Tags: jquery, html, css

I currently have a page with a show/hide function, where there is 2 buttons...

One for each content, but the problem I have is that I have to click one of them before the content showing, I know it is like it is, but I have no idea on how to change my code to make the first "puffwrap" to show when entering the site.

When entering the site, the "content" box in this picture below ain't showing.
http://piclair.com/35ogd

I want the button 1 to already be "clicked" so to say, I hope you understand what I mean and that someone can help me.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var $b = $('#container-wrapper li a');
        var $p = $('.puffwrap');

        $b.click(function() {
            var i = $b.index(this);
            $p.hide().eq(i).show()
        })
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: The best way to do this is set the puffwrap to display none in css and when you click the buttons just add a class say "active" or whatever. In your css, the active class has display block. You can add the active class in your markup to make the first one show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add code to your document ready handler to show the first one:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.puffwrap:first').show();
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I am forever grateful!

Comment: @Morpheus There's nothing about children in the original code. My answer will show the same thing as clicking on the first button.

Comment: That's something new to know. Haven't heard about `:first` before :)